# Как проверить подключен ли компьютер к интернету в .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите какими средствами можно проверить подключение компьютера к сети интернет.

Comment: есть в винде библиотека wininet, можно так http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/334375/is-there-a-simple-code-in-Csharp-to-check-if-pc-is  InternetGetConnectedState

Comment: Ваш коммент дублирует мой ответ, мой ответ был дан ранее.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь и что? К тому же комментарий появился на 3 минуты раньше вашего ответа. Наведите на дату редактирования и в подсказке увидите время его создания.

Comment: Зачем давать ответ в виде комментария со ссылкой на сторонний ресурс, если данное сообщество создано для хранения готовых решений на определенного рода вопросы. Ссылка может стать недоступной как минимум.

Comment: Да, @ДмитрийГвоздь ваш ответ лучше комментария но раскрывает не все аспекты. А если чесно, правильного ответа пожалуй нету, что б раскрыть тему, нужно проверить отдаёт ли DNS записи, и следить за доступностью DNS (что гарантирует доступность сети), что по идее должна делать OC Windows, а не программа. Если это заложено в  InternetGetConnectedState то это хорошо. Какая-то из ф-ций c# должна InternetGetConnectedState  получать напрямую. Надо все ответы протестировать и сделать вывод:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Или например таким классом можно воспользоваться.

```
class InernetChecker
{
    [DllImport("WININET", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(
        ref InternetConnectionState lpdwFlags, 
        int dwReserved);

    [Flags]
    enum InternetConnectionState: int
    {
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM      = 0x1,
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN        = 0x2,
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY      = 0x4,
        INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED         = 0x10,
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE    = 0x20,
        INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED = 0x40
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        InternetConnectionState flags = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(
            "InternetGetConnectedState : {0} - {1}",
            (InternetGetConnectedState(ref flags, 0)?"ONLINE":"OFFLINE"),
            flags
            );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Например, попытаться обратиться с помощью `WebClient` к какому-нибудь адресу:

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Или использовать пинг, как менее потребляющий трафик способ:

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    var ping = new Ping();
    String host = "google.com";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
    int timeout = 1000;
    var options = new PingOptions();
    try
    {
        var reply = ping.Send(host, timeout, buffer, options);
        return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309319/1985167)

Comment: Не лучшее решение, особенно если мониторить нужно раз в 5 секунд:)

Comment: @nick_n_a ну, о сценарии использования автор ничего не сообщил.

Comment: А потом в свет выходит софт который безжалосно и безполезно качает трафик интернета)))))), а если таких миллион - смерть бедному гуглу

Comment: @nick_n_a ну а как иначе. Наличие подключенной сети еще не значит, что она имеет выход в интернет.

Comment: пинг это удобно, но при отвалившемся DNS, пинг пройдет, а связи у большинства приложений не будет. Но если программа для которой проверяется соединение, работает строго по IP, то вполне подойдет

Answer (score 4):

Возможно   `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` 
даст нужный результат,  так же список доступных соидинений можно посмотреть тут

`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`